# Where is the *meghanada-server-log*

Tags: java

I recently installed `meghanada-mode` from melpa to help with some Java I am writing.  Mostly I like it.  However, it has started showing the following messages (in my `*Messages*` buffer):

```
Error:jetbrains.exodus.ExodusException: . Please check *meghanada-server-log*
WARN not match type
```

However, I cannot find a buffer by that name, nor a file (using the find command).

Moreover, if I compile my project (with Maven) it gives no errors and runs, but I assume something is not completely correct and would like to fix it.  However, I don't know where to look.

Comment: by convention buffers whose name start with an '*' aren't associated to files, so you won't find it in the filesystem. I cannot help you with why isn't there, except if the server isn't running.

Comment: Do you know how to check to see if the server is running?

Comment: And as mysteriously as the message appeared.  It has disappeared.

Comment: And then reappeared, but then I figured out why and added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `*meghanada-server-log*` only exists in the Emacs which started the meghanada server (with the `meghanada-server-start` command, which gets implicitly run when you turn on `meghanada-mode`).

So, if you start a 2nd Emacs, it will find the server running and not have that buffer.

Moreover, if you kill the 1st Emacs (the one that started the server) you can get the error messages I was referring to (because killing that emacs will kill the server), but not have the buffer to look in (because the 2nd Emacs didn't start the server and thus didn't create that buffer).

However, the messages will go away if you either:

1. Start another Emacs and have it turn on `meghanada-mode` for some file, whence it will find that the server is not running, because killing the 1st emacs killed it (causing the error message) and restart it.

or

2. Explicitly restart the `meghanada-server` with:

```
C-xmeghanada-server-kill
C-xmeghanada-server-start
```

Comment: As suggestion, in such scenario I'd run emacs in daemon mode and will connect to it with emacsclient.

Comment: Actually, that's the inverse of what I want.  My emacs tends to get too full of stuff and I need to kill it from time to time to do a "global garbage collect".  So, having a server running, would make the situation worse, but thanks for the suggestion.